# Расплывается текст UI при сборке окон интерфейса

Tags: unity3d, шрифты, ui, unity3d-ui

День добрый. 
Сделано небольшое приложение для моделирования, необходимо собрать к нему мало мальский интерфейс. Собираю окно из префабов отдельных элементов интерфейса с использование `Layout` групп выравнивания.

Дизайнер наша заложила что размер шрифта должен быть 14, выдала шрифты. Я шрифт закинул в проект, выставил размеры в текстовых полях, полях ввода, выпадающих списках и т.п. Текст выглядит очень размытым. Самое неприятное что при движении окна элементы начинают плыть еще больше, при этом выборочно, одни становятся четче, другие размываются. то же касается и мелких графических элементов Подозреваю что связано это с округлением, когда пиксель попадает между отдельными точками он размывается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`CanvasScaller` настроил под конкретное разрешение экрана, так вроде картинка выглядит почетче.

Подскажите у кого есть опыт, что делаю не так?

Comment: В editor окне всегда так, запусти посмотри в game окне

Comment: Да немножко получше, но все равно наблюдается размытие текста небольшое, особенно напрягает, что это только под конкретное разрешение.

Comment: Разверни окно на максимум и смотри, билдани на крайняк, это 90% проблема чисто окон Unity.